# apt not updating from desired source

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, ppa

I'm trying to update my version of the skrooge software. This is normally done by retrieving the package from `ppa:s-mankowski/ppa-kf5`, which I have added to my sources list using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:s-mankowski/ppa-kf5`.

When I perform a `sudo apt update`, I get the following results:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-mankowski/ppa-kf5/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease 
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

As you can see, the mankowski link is in the results for being updated.  However, check out the results from the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-cache madison skrooge
   skrooge | 2.21.1-1build2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
$ sudo apt-cache policy skrooge
skrooge:
  Installed: 2.21.1-1build2
  Candidate: 2.21.1-1build2
  Version table:
 *** 2.21.1-1build2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How do I get apt to recognize my mankowski link and pull the skrooge 2.24.6 update from that?

UPDATE EDIT:
Here is my normal upgrade line and the current result:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get clean
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                             
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/s-mankowski/ppa-kf5/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]             
Fetched 324 kB in 1s (499 kB/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

As can be seen, it doesn't want to update skrooge here, either.

Comment: Please see my edit in my answer.

Comment: The binary package is named `skrooge-kf5`, see [its page on PPA](https://launchpad.net/~s-mankowski/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-kf5/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal) you have to install it with `sudo apt-get install skrooge-kf5`  as mook765 says in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you ran `sudo apt update` (which updates the package cache), you need to run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

to effectively upgrade the package.

In your case this does not help. The name of the package in the added repository is `skrooge-kf5` and you'll need to explicitely install it with

```
sudo apt install skrooge-kf5
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've added the result of my upgrade command to the question above.